# ChallengeResult RedirectUri ignored after a delayed login in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have a ChallengeResult authenticating with Azure AD which doesn't return to the RedirectUri configured, if the user sits on the login page for several minutes before actually signing in. It works fine if the user logs in immediately.

The setup includes:

- Azure AD authentication through OpenId Connect
- CallbackPath: "~/signin-oidc"
- A login API

  ```
   [AllowAnonymous]
   [HttpGet("Login")]
   public IActionResult Login()
   {
       return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties
       {
           RedirectUri = "http://google.com",
       }, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
   }
  ```

Instead the user lands on the CallbackPath and a 500 error as a result. The login itself is successful - the token is received but the user lands on the wrong page.

I expect for the login request to follow a path along the lines:

```
.Net Core App > Azure AD login page > .Net Core App callback path > Redirect Uri
```

Please let me know if I can provide more information. Thanks.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: The error is http 500 error: "This page isn’t working... localhost is currently unable to handle this request." 

It's just a consequence of it redirecting to the CallbackPath; It happens whenever I navigate to the URL I configure as the CallbackPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the behaviour in .NET Core when the 'correlation' and 'nonce' cookies from the OpenIdConnect configuration expire. By default this is around 15 minutes. Perhaps this should be categorized as a bug.

I can increase these for now.

This answer is thanks to: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/24643.